# How to get and display keys and corresponding values of object properties of MultiMap in JSP Page

Tags: jsp, servlets, collections, jstl, guava

I didn't know how to iterate

My datatype is
Multimap<String, AlbumAndAlbumType> in which the String holds the type of albums/which genre and the values consists the list of objects of type AlbumAndAlbumType

I retrieved data from db but I don't know how to iterate and display them in a jsp page.

the multimap returns as follows

{Kollywood Private Albums=[

AlbumAndAlbumType [album_id=48, album_name=Orasaadha, album_type_id=28, album_image=null, album_description=Orasaadha Private Album, language=TAMIL, type_name=Kollywood Private Albums, type_description=Kollywood Private Albums],.........

]}

the String (Kollywood Private Albums) is key and the values are list of objects of class type(AlbumAndAlbumType)

Here I want to display heading(h2) as key and iterate the values of that key and need to display all the album names(album_name) in heading(h4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<c:forEach..></c:forEach>` to iterate through your mutlimap .Suppose your multimap value is in some session attribute then do like below :

```
 <%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <!--here "ses" is name of session attribute -->  
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${ses.asMap()}">
        <h2> <c:out value="${entry.key}"/></h2>
        <br/>Values:
        <c:forEach var="currentValue" items="${entry.value}">
            <h4> <c:out value="${currentValue.album_id}"/>  </h4>
                  <h4><c:out value="${currentValue.album_name}"/></h4>
            //..so on 
           
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
```